# How to set cmd variables to values with on or off?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

How can a cmd variable be set to the values `on` or `off`? Here is the output of an interactive cmd.exe session:

```
c:\>echo %myvar%
%myvar%

c:\>set myvar=x

c:\>echo %myvar%
x

c:\>set myvar=on

c:\>echo %myvar%

c:\>set myvar=off

c:\>echo %myvar%
```

after this last command, the command session becomes unresponsive and I need to manually close the command window. Do these values `on` or `off` hold special powers? Also `ON` or `OFF` have similar effect, so this is case-insensitive.

The closest I can get is to use quotes:

```
c:\>set myvar="on"

c:\>echo %myvar%
"on"
```

however, this is unacceptable since the variable contains quote characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`on` and `off` by themselves are valid variable values.

The issue is with the fact that `echo` takes the strings `on` and `off` as arguments to activate or deactivate the cmd feature of displaying a line of code before executing it.

The easiest way around this is to use `echo(` instead of `echo`.

```
set var=on
echo(%var%
```

The second easiest way around this is to have literally any additional string in the `echo` command. Aesthetically, I'd recommend using a backspace character (ALT+08) to delete a previous character and then write `on` or `off`.

```
set var=on
for /f %%a in ('"prompt;$H&for %%b in (0) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
echo .%BS%%var%
```

Comment: You could also use `echo/`…